# square of a permutation cycle

Tags: permutations

$$\sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8  &9 \\ 
 1&5  &7  &4  &6  &9  &3  &2  &8 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\sigma^{2} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8  &9  \\ 
1&  6&3  &4  &9  &8 &7  &5  & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Given $$\sigma$$ I found $$\sigma^2.$$

I want to find $$\sigma^{-2}$$ but I'm being told that my permutation cycle for $\sigma^2$ is wrong.
Very frustrating.

Please help...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: For the $\sigma$ you gave, your value for $\sigma^2$ looks correct to me. Who says it's wrong?

Comment: The column for 6 is missing in $\sigma^2$. That's probably just a typo.

Comment: Well, I looked at a given solution for $$\sigma^{-2}$$ and since the inverse is the reverse of the elements in a cycle, the solution for the inverse of the inverse does not correspond to mine.
I'm told that the solution for sigma-inverse is (29586)

Comment: Aha, you are confusing the mapping notation for a permutation with the cycle notation.  By the way, to get $\sigma^{-2}$ use `$\sigma^{-2}$`.

Comment: If my solution to $$\sigma^{-2}$$ is correct, then isn't the inverse just the reverse order of the elements?

Comment: With your notation (and with the added column for $\sigma^2(6)$, the inverse is just the table flipped on its head (and the columns sorted).

Comment: @Arthur I don't understand

Comment: @delta I explained Arthur's comment below.

Comment: Your use of the word "cycle" makes me wonder whether there is a misunderstanding here.  A cycle of a permutation is something never mentioned in your proposed value of $\sigma^2$.  And also, there is a missing column -- the one headed by $6$ -- in your array representing $\sigma^2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

Permutations are represented in two ways.  One is a verbose description of the mapping:  $$\sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8  &9 \\ 
 1&5  &7  &4  &6  &9  &3  &2  &8 
\end{bmatrix}$$ means that $1$ goes to $1$, $2$ goes to $5$, and so on.

We abbreviate this to *cycle* notation, which is more compact and also more revealing of important structure.  This permutation abbreviates to $$(1)(25698)(37)(4)$$ which means the same thing as before, only more compactly.  The $(25698)$ means that $2$ goes to $5$, $5$ goes to $6$, $6$ goes to $9$, $9$ goes to $8$, and $8$ goes back to $2$.  Then we abbreviate further by dropping the $(1)$ and $(4)$, which can be inferred even if not written explicitly.

In the *cycle* notation, $\sigma^2$ is indeed written $(26859)$, as you should check.  You are being asked to write $\sigma^{-2}$ in the compact cycle notation.

---

The inverse of a permutation $p$ is another permutation that un-does the effect of $p$.  If $p$ takes $3$ to $7$, then $p^{-1}$ should take $7$ to $3$.  Let's take a simple example:

$$p = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5 \\ 
 4&5  &2 &1  &3   
\end{bmatrix}$$

The inverse of $p$, in mapping notation, is

$$p^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
 4&5  &2 &1  &3  \\ 
1 &2  &3  &4  &5 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

because where $p$ took $2$ to $5$, $p^{-1}$ takes $5$ to $2$. As commented earlier, we have “flipped the notation upside down”.  We usually arrange the columns in order:

$$p^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5 \\ 
4 & 3& 5 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

In *cycle* notation, $p$ is written $(14)(253)$.  Again, this says that $2$ goes to $5$. As you observed in the comments, you can find $p^{-1}$ by writing the cycle notation for $p$ backwards: $$p^{-1} = (352)(41)$$ which we would usually write as $$p^{-1} = (14)(235).$$  Again, notice that this says that $p^{-1}$ takes $5$ to $2$, as before.

Comment: What I get and observed to be for $$\sigma^{2}$$ is (1)(26)(3)(4)(592)(7)(89)
More compactly, we get (26)(592)(89)

Comment: No, because that says that $\sigma^2$ takes $8$ to $9$.  But as you correctly said in your original question,  $\sigma^2$ actually takes $8$ to $5$.

Comment: It takes 8 to 5 and takes 5 to 9 and 9 to 2 and 2 to 6. Don't we 'linked' them?

Comment: I used the same reasoning for $$\sigma$$ and for most other questions and it turned out to be correct.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "linked".  Since $\sigma^2$ takes $8$ to $5$, $5$ to $9$, $9$ to $2$, $2$ to $6$, and $6$ to $8$, as you correctly said, you write $(85926)$, or $(26859)$, which means the same thing.

Comment: I did a careful check.
I get (1)(26)(3)(4)(5926)(85) and removing 'redundancies', the form we have is (28596). But the order of the elements isn't an exact fit. I suppose order is of no significance?

Comment: So order does not matter. That's probably the take home lesson...

Comment: Order of the individual cycles matters, unless they are disjoint. (That is, unless they have no numbers in common.)  So $(12)(34)$ is the same as $(34)(12)$, but $(12)(13)$ is different from $(13)(12)$.   And order of the elements of a cycle matters, but the place in the cycle that you start does not matter.  $(1234)$ is the same as $(2341)$ and $(3412)$, but not the same as $(1324)$.